# Is there a simpler and smarter/lighter (not faster) android emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator

The Android emulator is soooo stupid!  OK, it's nice to see the first time all these fake apps and moving around in an emulated mobile ... But after that, you mainly -- if not only -- need to see just how your app runs!  All the other paraphernalia just make the emulator unncessesarily slower and more memory hungry.

Does anyone know how to simplify the Android emulator or if there's a third party emulator that is not so stupid?

(If I continue searching in the Internet, I will most probably solve this problem, maybe in a few days (!), but I'm already fed up, because I can only find how to make the emulator faster but not how to make it smarter.)

Comment: That's a bad idea because it would make the emulator dumber.  The idea is to come as close as you can to the actual environment, given the hardware differences.  Not having those other things would make it a less realistic environment and would make it give incorrect results.  If anything I would want it to be even closer to a real phone, not less like it.

Comment: I didn't say that it shouldn't be so elaborated ... But only when needed.  And then, **you can always use your device itself** if you need a real environment.  But most of the times you only need to just to test your app ... So, what's the use to even have to "unlock" the avd each time you open it?!  This is what I meant by "stupid" ...

Comment: Then turn off screen locks. But they're actually useful, they let you test what happens when they turn on for a user, which can be a source of bugs. You're just wrong here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried Genymotion? https://www.genymotion.com
It´s an Android simulator and free for personal projects.
I couldn´t imagine developing without it.

If you are developing using Intellij/Android Studio there is also a plugin available to start the device right from the IDE.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. It sounds promising. I will test it soon.   I started using the Android Studio IDE but I find it kind of heavy (although I have only little ecperience with it).  So I switched to Eclipse IDE, which is lighter and about 80% more effective resources-wise than Studio. It also launches the emulator when you Run a project.  However, since the time of my question, I have upgraded my RAM, so I can leave the emulator always open. This partially solves the problem. Still, I don't know if the emulator would react faster if it were "lighter" ...

Comment: I haven't used the emulator supplied by Google sinced I tried out Genymotion. If I have to test something that can't be done on the genymotion (like using google play services) I just use the phone :).

I would highly recommending sticking to Android Studio as (imo) it is far superior for Android development :)